# Getting a reference to the rendering thread, to allow thread safe data access

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, .net-4.0, dispatcher

Recently I have been running into issues involving the use of multiple threads and sharing access to properties which are bound to WPF controls. These crashes tend to occur at random places in time, but can be replicated with persistance.

So what I wanted to try and do to allow thread safe data access to classes which are bound to WPF controls is gain a reference to the rendering thread dispatcher and make sure in my view models that this dispatcher is used to access their properties.

Is this concept sound? Will it allow the data which is bound to my controls to be accessed from other threads? (by accessed I do mean get/set).

How can I get a reference to the rendering thread? Can I simply get a reference to the thread which creates an instance of the App class?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as I know, I think `Application.Current.Dispatcher` will **always** give you the UI dispatcher so there is **really no need** to have a special code to gain access to the data bidning dispatcher (which should be the UI dispatcher itself).

Comment: The (very edge-case) exception is that it's possible to have multiple dispatchers: if you spawn a thread and create a window from that thread, it'll have a different dispatcher & UI thread.

Comment: In WPF that would need another STA thread. But in WPF only one STA can exist which is the UI. Correct me if I am wrong.